# How to prevent logical duplicates in a unary one to many SQL relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

In a non directional unary relationship what would be the best option to prevent logical duplicates?

E.G.

Main table

```
ID
--
1
2
```

Relational table

```
ID1    ID2
-----------
1      2
2      1
```

Entry two in the relational table is already logically represented by the first entry as the relationship is non directional

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, having both rows in the table is very handy for queries.  That said, if you only want one, there here are two options.

First, insist that `id1 < id2` and that the pair be unique:

```
alter table relations add constraint check (id1 < id2);
alter table relations add constraint unique (id1, id2);
```

This might have some unintended consequences.  You are not able to insert `(2, 1)` into the table.

A second approach is to create a function-based unique index.  Not all databases support this directly, but there is often similar syntax available.  Most databases support `least()` and `greatest()`, so:

```
create unique index unq_id1_id2
    on (least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2));
```

In SQL Server, you can do this with computed columns:

```
alter table relations add least_id1_id2 as
    (case when id1 < id2 then id1 else id2 end) persisted;

alter table relations add greatest_id1_id2 as
    (case when id1 < id2 then id2 else id1 end) persisted;

create unique index unq_relations_id1_id2 on relations(least_id1_id2, greatest_id1_id2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cda2fa63dbafa7bd60ae73641233f528) is a db<>fiddle.